# What is the difference between nunit3 xml format and nunit2 xml format?

Tags: xml, automation, nunit, nunit-3.0, nunit-2.5.9

On NUnit 3 release a new xml format of tests report appeared. It's nunit3 format.

There are a little information about it https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line.

**It's told there:**

> The --result option may use any of the following formats:
>
> nunit3 - the native XML format for NUnit 3.0 nunit2 - legacy XML
>   format used by earlier releases of NUnit The --explore option may use
>   any of the following formats:
>
> nunit3 - the native XML format for NUnit 3.0 cases - a text file
>   listing the full names of all test cases. If --explore is used without
>   any specification following, a list of test cases is output to the
>   console.

So for now we can use the next console param: `--result=TestResults.xml;format=nunit3`
and it will create report in nunit3 format.

**So my question is:** what is the difference between these 2 formats?

Actually I didn't notice any changes but I use TeamCity to publish tests results so maybe that's why.

Answer (score 4):

The internal xsd of the results file has changed to provide [more information](https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-test-nunit/issues/75).

The difference is in the xml format itself ie xsd

- [nunit 2.0 schema sample](https://github.com/martinmcwhorter/karma-nunit2-reporter/blob/master/nunit-schema.xsd)
- [nunit 3.0 xml details](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Result-XML-Format)

TeamCity has done the hard work to leave you unaffected by the change.